# Magento PHP if statement "load both blocks" , else load only one?

Tags: php, magento

maybe it is something simple but i am not really good with php
With this code i am able to load the static blocks styled in top of category in Magento and the subcategories in the bottom when the top category has child
What i am trying to do is that when there is no child category it should only load the block
otherwise because of styling it will hold the place that the subcat had position.
Please have a look on my code and maybe you understand:

```
<?php
    $_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
    $_imgHtml   = '';
    if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
        $_imgHtml = '<div class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" /></div>';
        $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
    }
    $_catHtml = $this->getChildHtml('catalog.inline.subcat');
?>
<?php if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>

// load the blocks styled with ul and il backgrounds 

                <ul class="inline-categories"> 
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId(   $this->getCurrentCategory()->getLandingPage()    )->toHtml() ?> 
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                <li<?php if($_i == 1):?> class="first"<?php endif ?>><a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>>    
                <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a> (<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)</li>
                <?php endforeach ?> 
                <?php endif; ?>     
                </ul>

                // here i need something like an "else" because the if($count) allready understand that this is not on count so should only load this that is without style //

               <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId(   $this->getCurrentCategory()->getLandingPage()    )->toHtml() ?> 

                //end of this else thing, now should only load the cms/block alone without anything / end of page we are done...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP's if/else statements like this:

```
<?php if ($_count): ?>

    stuff if $_count is non-zero

<?php else: ?>

    other stuff if $_count is zero

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks so much, i sorted this out exactly the same way just 5' after i post here!!guess i'm getting better :)